# Prevent Multiple iPhone Sessions

Tags: ios, node.js, authentication

I have an iPhone app that uses token based authentication whenever a user logs on with a Node backend. However, if that same user were to log in to the application from another phone I want to allow this but sign them out on the first phone. How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With token based authentication you would need to issue them a new token, and expire their old one(s). If a user attempts to access resources with an expired token deny it. This will require you to look up sessions by user.